# go run doesnt get the latest tag

Tags: go, go-modules

I'm playing with GraphQL in Go and I was trying to get [gqlgen](https://github.com/99designs/gqlgen) tool using the familiar `go run` command.

I was expecting it to retrieve the latest available tag, instead I"m somehow getting a tag which does not seem to exist in the repo at all:

```
$ go run github.com/99designs/gqlgen version
v0.9.1-dev
```

I would expect the above to return per [the latest tag](https://github.com/99designs/gqlgen/releases)

```
v0.13.0
```

Go version installed on my workstation:

```
$ go version
go version go1.15.5 darwin/amd64
```

Anyone has any ideas what's going on?

**UPDATE:** disabling `GOPROXY` does not help

**UPDATE2:** it turns out the version is hardcoded into `version.go` as you can see [here](https://github.com/99designs/gqlgen/blob/master/graphql/version.go), but even if `go run` gets the master instead of the latest tag, you'd still expect the output to be `0.13.0-dev` as per the [master branch](https://github.com/99designs/gqlgen/blob/master/graphql/version.go) Instead I suspect there is some string ordering of versions of tags which orders `0.9.*` above `0.1*.*`

Comment: You should not be using `go run` if the versions matter in any way. It’s better to just avoid it altogether.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`go run` does not currently support running a specific version of a binary, but note that there is an [accepted Go proposal](https://golang.org/issue/42088) to add that functionality in a future release of the `go` command.

As of Go 1.16, you can instead `go install` the binary at a specific version, and then run that binary from its install location (either `$(go env GOBIN)` or `$(go env GOPATH)/bin`).

```
$ GOBIN=~/bin go install github.com/99designs/gqlgen@latest
$ ~/bin/gqlgen ...
```

Comment: For Go versions through Go 1.16, `go run` runs whatever version is already indicated by the dependencies of the current module. You can identify that version using `go list -f '{{with .Module}}{{.Path}} {{.Version}}{{end}}' github.com/99designs/gqlgen`.

Answer (score 0):

I think the version command was misconfigured on build, and that v0.9.1-dev was not the tag at build time.